# Removing a link that contains particular text

Tags: javascript

I'm building a glossary page. I have a list of each letter of the alphabet at the top of the page, linking via anchor text to the correct section of content. 
I want to remove the link from the letter if the letter has no terms.

I'm not getting any errors, but the code is not removing the link, or having any affect as far as I can tell.

Trying to remove link for B

```js
        function removeLink (){

        var letternavcontent = document.getElementById("letternav").innerHTML;
        var letter = document.getElementsByClassName("letter");

         if ( letternavcontent.indexOf('B') > -1) {
         letter.removeAttribute("href");
         }
         }
```

```html
        <p id="letternav">| <a class="letter" 
        href="/glossary.html#a">A</a> | <a class="letter" 
        href="/glossary.html#b">B</a></p>
```

Comment: `letter` will be an array or NodeList (notice getElement**s**ByClassName).  `removeAttribute` is an Element method.  You will have to loop over the NodeList to use it

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "remove the link".  Do you want it to no longer be inside an anchor tag?

Comment: Do you want to remove the anchor tag or just delete the attribute href ? looks like you want to remove the anchor tag.

Comment: I want to remove the whole link, so it's unclickable

Comment: access the parent element -> loop through its children -> check if contains certain text then parent.removeChild to remove the anchor tag.

Comment: @HeatherWebDev please edit your question to include the removal of the link entirely, if that is one of your desired criteria in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KbaLYR).

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns *all* the elements with that class name, not just one. So you must loop through this list and check each one.

```
function removeLink (){

  var letter = document.getElementsByClassName("letter");

  for (var i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
    if (letter[i].innerHTML.indexOf('B') > -1) {
      letter[i].removeAttribute("href");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also please review the question, as the comments have updated to say they want to remove the link entirely.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```js
const removeLinkFromLetter = letter => {

  // iterates over every letter element
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.letter')].forEach(elt => {
    // if the element has the specified letter as its text...
    if (elt.innerText.trim()==letter) {
      // ...change its content to the letter without the anchor tag
      elt.innerHTML = letter;
    }
  });

}

window.onload = () => {
  removeLinkFromLetter('A');
}
```

```html
<p id="letternav">
  |
  <span class="letter">
    <a href="/glossary.html#a">
      A
    </a>
  </span>
  |
  <span class="letter">
    <a href="/glossary.html#b">
      B
    </a>
  </span>
  |
</p>
```